# How to change Language for non-Unicode programs in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, unicode

There has always been a "Language for non-Unicode programs" settings in the "Region and Language" settings in XP, Vista and 7.

I installed Windows 8 (had some unrelated problems, so I had to revert to Windows 7 though), and I tried installing a piece of software that was not made with Unicode, but Shift-JIS (Japanese). The installer obviously shows incorrect glyphs, and the installer is unusable.

So I tried changing the "Language for non-Unicode programs" setting, but I noticed that the entire language applet was rebuilt from scratch.

As I reverted to Windows 7, I can't tinker with it until I solve the other problems and can get to install 8 again. But in the meantime, does anybody know where can I change this setting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Windows 7's `Region and Language` has been split up in Windows 8 to separate `Region` and `Language` Control Panel applets.

1. Go to `Control Panel` (the desktop version)
2. `Clock, Language, and Region`
3. `Region`
   [image: 2]
4. Click on the `Administrative` tab on the top
5. Under `Language for non-Unicode programs`, select the button `Change system locale`, then select `Japanese` or whichever Asian display language you would like
6. Restart your computer

The Japanese characters should display fine now.

---

**Windows 7 Region and Language Applet**
[image: 1]

**Windows 8 Language Applet**
[image: 3]

Comment: Would be nice if we change the language of a particular application! I have applications that are in different languages.

Comment: @AeroWindwalker See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Also there are tools to change locale for a single application:

1. [Locale Emulator](http://pooi.moe/Locale-Emulator/).
2. [Ntleas](https://ntlea.codeplex.com/).
3. Micosoft AppLocale Wizard, which is not updated for a decade, and even not hosted for a few years so no one can find a copy of it, but it seems still [some people](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9837a3c7-ec4f-4d7f-8ba7-08ca91fbbfe0/applocale?forum=win10itproapps) utilize it through compatibility troubleshooter, or through [this more complex approach](http://users.wfu.edu/yipcw/atg/microsoft/applocale/).