# What exactly is the consequence of changing the "system locale" in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, language, localization

I read http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/change-the-system-locale (windows 8 linked me to this help page)

and I still can't completely understand what that means. In which way is the system locale different than the *display language*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**System Locale** (Language for non-Unicode Programs):

> This setting has three major purposes:
>
> - Specifies the default ANSI, OEM, MAC, and EBCDIC ***code pages to use for non-Unicode programs***.
> - Specifies some of the font linking preferences for CJK fonts and for legacy bitmap fonts.
> - Specifies application behavior when developers incorrectly use this setting rather than the DEFAULT USER LOCALE.

[image: 1] [image: 2]

---

**User Locale** (Standards and Formats):

> This setting controls the way information is presented - the sort order in list boxes, the ***format of date, time, number, and currency values, the calendar*** you prefer to use.

[image: 3]

---

**Input Locale** (Input Method/Language):

> This setting specifies the ***input language and the method for input devices, such as the keyboard layout***. The input locale (also called input language) is a per-process setting that describes an input language (for example, Greek) and an input method (for example, the keyboard).

[image: 4]

---

**Display Language**

> This setting specifies the default system ***language to display user interface (UI) items*** (such as menus, dialog boxes, and help files).

[image: 5]

---

**References**

- Michael Kaplan - [What is my locale? Well, which locale do you mean?](https://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/02/01/364707.html)
- [Windows Locales and Languages FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20160722113342/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688174.aspx)
- TechNet - [SystemLocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc766324%28v=ws.10%29), [UserLocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc748973%28v=ws.10%29), [InputLocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc748926%28v=ws.10%29), [UILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc766421%28v=ws.10%29)
- [Windows 8 language packs are available](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/language-packs-are-available-for-windows-8-and-for-windows-rt-358f37fa-7662-3078-dfb3-915991b572d4)
- Building Windows 8 - [Using the language you want](https://web.archive.org/web/20151127200508/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/21/using-the-language-you-want.aspx)
- [How to change Language for non-Unicode programs in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/497857)
- [How can I change the spell check and auto-correction language of IE10/Windows8?](https://superuser.com/questions/480540)

Comment: Oh god I hate everything about this. Thanks for the work though.

Comment: Confusing? Certainly! (Even [Kaplan](http://www.unicodeconference.org/bios.htm), although he's an MS employee working on i18n/localisation/globalisation support, agrees.) Anyway, hope this helped clear things up a bit.