# How to get windows explorer to display Russian characters?

Tags: windows-7

I have some files which have Russian characters in the file names. How can I get Windows to display those characters (see screenshot)?

[image]

I do seem to have what is needed to display Russian. These files contain some Russian text and, when I open these files, I can see the Russian characters.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/503165/52492 (I've no idea if it helps but it may be worth trying)

Comment: There is a `convmv` package in cygwin. It converts between file name encodings. Would you care to try it and report back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't Windows Explorer, file names were corrupted somehow in the filesystem. Filesystem in Windows supports U+04xx cyrillic character range, but file names in your case have U+008x..U+00Fx characters instead.

How did you get these ones? If they were extracted from archive, then delete them, set Windows-1251 as code page for non-Unicode programs in Control Panel, and expand that archive again. If they were written under Linux via ntfs-3g/vfat driver, then reboot into linux, mount Windows partition correctly and copy these files again. So, you got the idea: it's filesystem who needs to be fixed, not the Explorer.

Comment: Yes, I did get it from an archive. How do I set the code page setting?

Comment: In your original post, someone wrote a comment. Click the link and see 2 first pictures

Answer (score 0):

Question is where you got them, right? I'm getting this with Japanese files, when sent to me in ZIPped form, that's why i decided to answer. If you were send them like i say, ask sender to resend packed with RAR, it will encode names in unicode. Alternate way is to alter your system locale to the same one your sender has, like RedGrittyBrick said, and look if you see tchem properly. Then rename them one by one, and Windows will also encode them with unicode, so you could revert to your original locale and see the names properly (this is a longshot, i admit).

Comment: I got them as a zip file. Too many files to rename.