# How to force a language for all websites

Tags: firefox, proxy, language, locale

I am currently living in UAE but I do not speak Arabic and almost all websites always show content in Arabic even though I have setup my preferred language to English in both my OS, which is Windows 8, and in Firefox as well by going into Options > Advance > Languages and removed any other languages from there.

I additionally tried to hard-code it in `about:config` as I read about it somewhere around here, a user suggested it but didn't work as well. I googled a lot about it and the only solution that seems to work is using a proxy but I don't want to use a proxy all the time so my question is; is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Just to make it clear, what I want to achieve here is that I want all the websites to display content in English instead of Arabic by default.

Comment: What websites do you visit? Are they multilingual?

Comment: Yes, most of them are. Like for e.g. Bing or IGN.

Comment: Are you always going to .com? Or .ar.co or whatever the region code might be?

Comment: My browser takes me to the local site but I always try to use a specific URL extension to force the region like google.co.uk

While it works for Google, there are other sites for which this doesn't work and content is displayed in Arabic language.

Comment: You can see whether setting your [user locale](http://superuser.com/a/503165/138343), location etc. to something other than UAE helps. However most likely they're geolocalizing based on your IP address, and that might not be so easy to overcome with many sites (unless perhaps you use a foreign proxy/VPN).

Comment: @Karan thanks for your reply but that doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: @techie007 I'm not talking about the search engine only, but the region/language detected by almost all the websites I visit. I fixed the google one with google.com/ncr

Comment: Are you directed to the English version of the site if you use a proxy that is located in the UK or the USA?

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar yes, I am directed to the English version of the site if I use a UK or USA based proxy server.