# Unable to directly input unicode characters with diacritical marks into PuTTY on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, putty, unicode

After moving to Windows 8, I can no longer directly input unicode characters into [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) session window. Like `ą`, `ę`, `ć`, `ń` using `Alt+<letter>` with `Polish (programmers)` keyboard layout.

- I have `Window -> Translation -> Remote character set` set to `UTF-8`.
- Typing directly using the physical keyboard connected to the server works.
- And, what is strange, **pasting** a text with these letters into PuTTY works, too.
- The server is using UTF-8. Here, `ąęółśćżźń` is being **pasted**:

  ```
  m@debian:~$ echo ąęółśćżźń > x ; file x
  x: UTF-8 Unicode text
  m@debian:~$
  ```
- Pressing e.g. `Alt+x`, that normally renders `ź`, in PuTTY window results in a normal latin `z`. Here, `żźżźżź` is being **pasted**:

  ```
  m@debian:~$ echo żźżźżź | md5sum
  1ff31403a1089c590ed55d42cdcd0f3e  -
  m@debian:~$
  ```

  Here, `żźżźżź` is being **typed**:

  ```
  m@debian:~$ echo zzzzzz | md5sum
  cd519e63e450d863e5ee02814bae016d  -
  m@debian:~$
  ```

  And here, a plain `zzzzzz` is being typed:

  ```
  m@debian:~$ echo zzzzzz | md5sum
  cd519e63e450d863e5ee02814bae016d  -
  m@debian:~$
  ```

  Same sum.
- The only letter with a diacritic that is typable is `ó` (which is also present in latin1 charset).
- This same **exact** executable *does work* on Windows 7.

My guess is that Windows 8 is somehow deciding that PuTTY is unable to process typed (?) non-latin1 characters and it changes them on-the-fly to their latin1 counterparts.

What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting "Language for non-Unicode programs" as suggested in https://superuser.com/a/497880/214569 helped.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me!

I had changed PuTTY's **font** previously. The only change that I needed was reverting it to `Courier New` (in <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Appearance</kbd>).

[image]

Also choose 'UTF-8' in <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Translation</kbd>.

[image]