# Make PuTTY send umlauts and other special characters to Debian Linux server

Tags: linux, keyboard, putty

I have a Debian Jessie server that I am connecting to via PuTTY. While displaying umlauts and other special characters does work, I cannot type them with the keyboard. For <kbd>é</kbd>, <kbd>è</kbd>, <kbd>ä</kbd> or <kbd>ß</kbd> I simply hear a bell, for <kbd>ö</kbd> bash changes to `(arg: 6)` and for <kbd>ü</kbd> I get something from the bash history (not the latest entry though).

I tried setting the terminal-type string to `linux` or `putty`, but it didn't change anything. How can I fix the special keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to type special characters in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux)

Comment: No it's not. It's something specific to PuTTY because I don't have this problem using a Linux client connected via OpenSSH to the server.

Comment: Alternatively [this](https://superuser.com/questions/721852/unable-to-directly-input-unicode-characters-with-diacritical-marks-into-putty-on?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Unfortunately not. Also, I do have a German keyboard with those physical letters, I am not trying to enter umlauts using the Alt-key.

Comment: In putty, have you set the remote character set to `utf-8`? (Settings/Window/Translation)?

Comment: Yes. I also have matching locales set up. Displaying the chars is not a problem, it's only that I cannot send them to the server. :( If I have files with umlauts, or database entries with umlauts, they all show up fine using ls or mysql.