# Russian text dosen't display inside EXE's

Tags: windows, regional-settings

I am having an issue where russian text displays as wierd characters instead of what it is supposed to be. If you look at the picture I provided, please look at the bottom right below where it says "Sonic Riders Zero Gravity" (the text in the black box), and the title of the window. I am running Windows 8.1.

What I did so far: Added Russian keyboard language, changed locale to Russia, and restarted. Didn't work. My friend in Russia isn't having this issue, so it is something with my computer.

The text is supposed to be russian, but instead it is displaying some language I have never seen before.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Download **Microsoft Applocale** [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=13209).
2. Install it.
3. Set Applocale to run with your application using Russian.

In step 3 it should have created a shortcut for the application to run with Applocale
for you, eg in Desktop.

Run the application using the shortcut created and see if it works.

Comment: This. AppLocale is a bit of a pig of a piece of software, but it is usually the best approach.
Another good piece of software is HF pApploc, an augmented version by the users at HongFire: http://www.hongfire.com/forum/downloads.php?do=file&id=329
It seems to be suited mostly for running Japanese files, so I don't know how it copes with Russian, but I recommend giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with codepage.

Try following:

There are two files in your `C:\Windows\system32` folder: С_1252 and С_1251.
 1. Copy C_1251 somewhere;
 2. Rename it in new location to C_1252;
 3. Give yourself all permissions on original of file C_1252 in `system32`;
 4. Copy this file somewhere just in case and then remove original;
 5. Copy your renamed file from step 2 to `system32` folder;
 6. Reboot.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Got the BSOD every time I boot Windows, so I booted from my Linux partition and restored the old files that I copied from System32. Computers back to normal. Russian text still not displaying. Any other ideas?

Comment: OK, you may try to set locale for non-Unicode programs if not yet. It situated in `Control Panel` -> `Language` -> `Change date, time, or number formats` -> `Administrative` tab.

Comment: Tried that already, as stated in the question description.

Comment: No ideas then. Since you're Russain as I see, the most relevant word for your further search would be "кракозябры". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your non-unicode code page to Russia, this way every app that is not created using Unicode capable controls will use Russia code page to show content.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Search for it in Google,http://superuser.com/questions/497857/how-to-change-language-for-non-unicode-programs-in-windows-8

Comment: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/29081-language-non-unicode-programs-change-windows.html