# Greek characters not showing properly on a legacy windows app

Tags: windows, code-page

I have an old windows app, and in my machine Greek characters show up using a wrong codepage. Normally changing a setting in `Regional Settings` about what codepage to use for non-Unicode programs, solved such issues.

But not for this app, and specifically not on my machine. The last time I had to run this legacy app on my laptop, I found a tool that made a special link for your app and when you executed that, the app showed up properly.

I've formatted the laptop since, and unfortunately I've erased that tool too. So my question is. Does anyone know about such a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the tool, just a few moments after I posted the question. So, for future reference.

[NTLEA - NT Locale Emulator Advance - Home](https://ntlea.codeplex.com/)

More [here](https://superuser.com/questions/497857/how-to-change-language-for-non-unicode-programs-in-windows-8/1170441#1170441)