# Paste non-ASCII characters into console of a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, terminal, vmware-workstation

Host OS: Windows 10.0.15063 Build 15063 Enterprise
Guest OS: Ubuntu 18.04 Server (headless - no X Windows running)
VMWare Workstation 14.1.2 Pro

I am able to view non-ASCII characters in the Ubuntu console. If I attempt to paste non-ASCII characters into the console, Workstation returns a pop-up error: "Paste failed: An error occurred while pasting:... cannot be converted to keystrokes".

`Virtual Machine Settings` > `Options` > `Enhanced Keyboard` > `Use if available (recommended)` is currently selected.

`open-vm-tools` (Version 2:10.2.0-3ubuntu3) is installed on the guest OS.

How can I successfully paste non-ASCII characters from Windows into my virtual machine's console? Again, the console is already able to successfully *display* non-ASCII characters in files, for instance.

Comment: Are you getting the same error if you paste your text into plain text editor in the VM and from there into the console?

Comment: @miroxlav The VM is Ubuntu Server without X Windows so it only has a console. In the console I have tmux running with different windows for emacs, terminal, etc.

Comment: My guess would be you can't. The message implies it's trying to convert them to actual key strokes. As such you likely need a suitable key mapping either on your host or guest. The easiest way to work around this would probably to just use SSH to connect to your guest.

Comment: VMware tools allows copy/paste from a GUI environment through back-channel memory access and communication between the host and guest software, but this is not relevant to the console. In the past I've even had to resort to shared files for passing such text. You will probably have better success by using SSH instead of the console.

Comment: I tried SSH'ing and at least input Unicode characters appeared but they were junk characters. I then [changed Language for non-Unicode programs](https://superuser.com/questions/497857/how-to-change-language-for-non-unicode-programs-in-windows-8) and finally characters appeared as desired. You are welcome to provide an 'Answer' in order to reap the 50 point bounty.

Comment: Done as requested. Feel free to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original comment :

> VMware tools allows copy/paste from a GUI environment through back-channel memory access and communication between the host and guest software, but this is not relevant to the console. In the past I've even had to resort to shared files for passing such text. You will probably have better success by using SSH instead of the console.

The poster tried SSH and some Unicode characters did appear,
but they were weird.
He then followed
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/497880/8672)
in the post
[How to change Language for non-Unicode programs in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/497857/how-to-change-language-for-non-unicode-programs-in-windows-8),
to set a `Language for non-Unicode programs`, and finally the problem
was solved.